# State is not updated properly when using React.memo and useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-usecallback, react.memo

My problem is quite common but it is not easy to figure out what is wrong with my example. I have nested components Parent->Child1->Child2. State and setState are passed in props to child components. I want to avoid re-renders in child components when parent is updated and I want to avoid to re-render the whole list when only one item is changed.

Here is my sample https://plnkr.co/edit/6nKaKrgNIF7LSetN
As you can see when I change title in Parent or description in Child1, Child2 is not re-rendered, but when I change state in Child2, whole list is re-rendered plus there are some side-effects with state update.

Parent component. It contains title and .
For Child1 onChange I receive *prop* which I want to update in state and *value* for it. I use useCallback hook to avoid additional re-render in child components, you will see React.memo there

```
const Parent = ({ initialData }) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(initialData);
    console.log('render Parent');
    return <>
         <h2>Parent</h2>

        <input
            placeholder="title"
            value={data.title}
            onChange={
                React.useCallback((e) => {
                     setData(prev => ({ ...prev, title: e.target.value }))
                }, [])
            }
        />
        <br />
        <Child1
            data={data}
            onChange={
                React.useCallback((prop, value) => {
                    setData(
                        prev => {
                            prev[prop] = value;
                            const newState = { ...prev };
                            return newState;
                        }
                    );
                }
                , []
                )
            }

        />
    </>
}
```

Then in Child1 wrapped with React.memo. It renders also Child2 in a list.

```
        const Child1 = React.memo(
            ({ data, onChange }) => {
                console.log('render Child1');
                return <>
                    <h3>Child1</h3>

                    <input
                        placeholder="description"
                        value={data.description}
                        onChange={(e) => { onChange('description', e.target.value) }}

                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    {data.list.map((element, index) => {
                        return <Child2
                            key={index} // don't do this in real
                            index={index}
                            data={element}
                            onChange={
                                React.useCallback(
                                    (prop, value) => {
                                        const newList = data.list.map((e, i) => {
                                            let newItem = { ...e };
                                            if (i == index) {
                                                newItem[prop] = value;
                                            }
                                            return newItem;
                                        });
                                        onChange('list', newList);
                                    }
                                    ,
                                    []
                                )
                            }
                        />
                    })}

                </>

            }
        )
```

Child2 is rendered in the list

```
        const Child2 = React.memo(({ index, data, onChange }) => {
            console.log('render Child2', index);
            return (

                <>
                    <h4>Child2</h4>

                    Country: <br />
                    <input
                        placeholder="country"
                        value={data.country}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange('country', e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    Region: <br />
                    <input
                        placeholder="region"
                        value={data.region}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange('region', e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    City: <br />
                    <input
                        placeholder="city"
                        value={data.city}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange('city', e.target.value)}
                    />

                    <hr />

                </>

            )
        }

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` in Child2 is calling `setData` from Parent, which updates Parent's state. Updating the state of Parent will trigger a re-render. Child1 re-renders because its `data` prop is changing (changing props will also trigger a re-render).

Try passing `title` in your dependency arrays in the useCallback functions in Parent and Child1 and see if that works. This should make the onChange function appear to be "changing" which should trigger re-renders down the component tree.

Comment: also, it should be added function to compare props  in React.memo, if there is complex objects in props, otherwise it will rerender component every time. I changed code a bit, like you suggested. It works much better, but anyway state resets in the list. Can you check please? https://plnkr.co/edit/TWesYjaZhUQ1IfDY?preview

Comment: it is interesting, that when I change for example first Child2 input, it works fine, but when I change another Child2 in the list, previous Child2 rerenders and resets to default state. Looks like component Child2 changes old list, but how can I get the latest state in useCallback?